# How often to check for network connection in iOS

Tags: ios

I am creating an app and I have some local data in the app which I have to sync to the server. I can only sync the data to the server if there is internet connection. If there is no internet connection, then the app will log the data temporarily and once the internet connection is back, the data will sync the data to the server.

My question here is how often should I check whether there is internet connection. Should I do this in the background? Or is it better to have the internet connections checks at certain screens of the app and if there is data, then I sync the data?

Need some suggestions on how to go about solving this problem.(Note: Intend to use Reachability to check for Internet connection)

Comment: Look at the Reachability class. You can set it up to notify you when reachability changes.

Comment: So when the notification comes, then I can submit the data in the background?

Comment: Your app wouldn't be in the background at the time. Or did you mean a background thread? If so, then yes.

Comment: U can check whenever u going to load stuff from the API and when the app going to recover from background

Comment: Ya i meant background thread. Once the notification comes, in the background thread, I submit the local data and store the results of the submission. This will be good right?

Comment: I want the app to submit the local data whenever the internet connection comes back whether the app is foreground or background.

Comment: ur app wont do anything if its in background, it have to be active to submit the data, probably u can create the check and submit in `applicationDidBecomeActive`, app in background and background thread is different stuff

Comment: You should have a look in the Background execution documentation :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html